# What the main reason for Bertrand Russell's skepticism and rejection of modal logic?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

It seems to me that Bertrand Russell was somewhat hostile to the idea that modality plays a role in logic.

Comment: See Jan Dejnozka, [The ontological foundation of Russell's theory of modality](http://www.members.tripod.com/~Jan_Dejnozka/onto_found_russell_modality.pdf) (1990) and ref to  B.Russell, [The Analysis of Matter](https://books.google.it/books?id=_GqBe7xIqeIC&pg=PA169) (1927), page 169.

Comment: See also B.Russell, [Necessity and possibility](https://books.google.it/books?id=zippibBi-aEC&pg=PA507) (1905): "*Necssary* and *contingent*, therefore, in so far as these are connected with *a priori* and *empirical*, have a purely epistemological importance, and are not notions which logic need take account of. [page 511]"

Answer (score 1):

I guess it was natural to be skeptical since at the time (1927) one didn't have a good semantics for modal operators, and so modal logic may not have seemed like proper mathematics.

That came only in the late 1950s with Kripke: possible worlds *x*, *y* and their accessibility relation *xRy*.